# Sorting/Ordering sequenced pairs of data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, linked-list, sql-order-by

I am trying to determine if there's a way to sort rows of a MySQL table that consists of start/finish columns.  (Could also be thought of as parent/child relations or other linked list arrangement)

Here's an example of how the data is currently stored:

```
id      start        finish
2       stepthree    stepfour
6       stepfive     stepsix
9       stepone      steptwo
78      stepfour     stepfive
121     steptwo      stepthree
```

(The id numbers in this are not relevant, just using them to indicate additional columns of arbitrary data)

I want to sort/display these row in order, presuming I am always starting with "stepone", that traverses the start-> finish chain like, each "finish" being followed by the row with it as a "start".

```
desired output
9       stepone      steptwo
121     steptwo      stepthree
2       stepthree    stepfour
78      stepfour     stepfive
6       stepfive     stepsix
```

There shouldn't be any branching/splits normally, just a sequential series of steps or states.  I can't use simple alpha sorting (in my case the start and finish values are codes created by a customer), but can't figure out any other way to order these using SQL.  I could programmatically do it using most languages, but stumped about doing it just with SQL.

Any clever ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend having another table that has each step mapped to its precedence order.

Then you can write a query to sort each row in the order of precedence of the start step.

Comment: True, although then I'd have 2 tables to maintain (and carefully keep in sync) when really only one of them is needed to preserve the sequence of steps.  If someone adds an additional step in someplace, I'd have to also remember to update that secondary table with the same info.   I was hoping to find a way to derive the sort order by traversing the one original table.